# Finding out whether 3 given functions exist

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

## Introduction

I am trying to find links between continuity, the existence of one-sided limits in specific points and the existence of a function in a specific point.

So I came up with these scenarios to test my knowledge. However, I don't know if these functions are even possible, so that's why I ask for your help.

[image]

(excuse the poor hand-drawn quality of this image, but I know about no graphing tool that can allow one to freely trace graphs without inputing a function beforehand and since I doubt all of these functions exist, I chose an unprofessional route of tracing the graphs)

### Cases

**Case #1**

The first case is supposed to represent the behaviour of a function in a specific point, $x$. For this point, both the one-sided limits exist (and, therefore, are finite), but are unequal (so the limit in that point does not exist, nor is the function continuous there). Moreover, the function is not defined in that point, which I tried to represent by drawing holes (this argument also enforces the lack of continuity).

**Case #2**

The second case is supposed to be similar to the first one, but with a changed parameter - now the function is defined at that point.
**Now, I know that one chooses to use both a hole and a filled spot for this representation (one head is a hole and the other one is a filled spot)**. What I can deduce from this is that the second case is not possible. But is it because it violates an inherent property of functions? It might be because $x$ is mapped twice on the $y$ axis. Not sure about this one.

**Case #3**

The third case is something I've wanted to ask ever since I had learned about functions. I suspect this might be impossible too, because it leaves some elements of the $x$ axis unmapped, but might it be possible in the realm of partial functions?

### Final notes

Confirming my doubts on these questions would help me understand basic calculus a lot better. Also, is there a link between having a function undefined in a point, and having the one-sided limits undefined at the same point? Or are these properties independently contributing to the existence of a limit in that point/continuity in that point/differentiability in that point?

Comment: Nucleophillic attack on math 

Comment: I chose this username when I first made an account on ChemSE. I love both mathematics and chemistry. :D

Comment: Your first and third functions are not defined on the whole real line: the first misses a point and the third an interval.  But on their reduced domains they seem to be  functions (assuming the third curve does not actually have vertical segments). As you say, the second is not a (single-valued) function

Comment: @Henry thank you for your answer! As I've stated, the first function is intended to miss a point, because it is not defined in that point. Also, are functions anything but single-valued? As far as I know, a function has every element of the domain mapped to one and only one element of the codomain.

Answer (score 1):

> How is not having a function defined in a point related to not having the one-sided limits defined in the same point?

For an arbitrary function, the definition at a point has no relation with the limits on side. If you put some constraints on the behaviour of function (eg: differentiable functions in complex analysis) , then a lot of 'behaviour' is implied. For example, a conce differentiable complex function is infinitely so.

Comment: Wouldn't that fraction be 1 all the time? $(x-1)/(x-1)$ gives 1 for every $x$ besides 1.

Comment: yes, if you want a more exotic function do $ \frac{x-1}{x-1} \cdot \sin x$, same thing but x=1 is whack

Comment: Oh, I thought you were attempting to find functions that have graphs similar to the ones I wrote about. Now I got it, you provided examples of discontinuities. I am familiar with the concepts of continuity and differentiability. I know about the conditions that have to be met for a function to be continuous or differentiable. My question essentialy was: how is not having a function defined in a point related to not having the one-sided limits defined in the same point?

Comment: Edited the  answer @TheRelentlessNucleophile

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly the answer I was looking for. Theoretically, two discrete factors come into play when analysing whether a function is continuous in a point or not: having the function defined at that specific point and having the one-sided limits defined at the same point, finite, equal to each other and finally equal to the value of the function. One easily manages to get from the existence of the one-sided limits to the other limit-related consequences in a cascade-like fashion, but I needed a *bridge* between undefined function in a point and undefined limits. [1/2]

Comment: Now it seems there isn't any *bridge* of this sort, and these two factors operate independently to give a continous function in a point. Have I got that right?

Comment: The existence of such a bridge is what makes a function a continuous function.  @TheRelentlessNucleophile

Answer (score 0):

Function is given as a mapping between two sets $A$ and $B$ the domain and the co domain. So in the first case the domain would not include the point it's not defined on (otherwise it wouldn't be a function), so the function would actually be continuous because we are only looking in the domain of the function.

For the third case one would choose a domain which would include only points where the function is defined and it would be continuous.

For the second it would be undefined since you have two points for the same $x$ from domain, and a function needs that every $x$ from domain is mapped to exactly one value from the co domain.

Comment: Why wouldn't the first one be considered a function if the domain were to include the point? Isn't it essentially a jump discontinuity but with an undefined mapping on the y axis? Also, how could it be continuous, when continuous functions are informally defined as functions that can be traced without lifting the pencil off the paper. That function clearly has a jump. Or is this a case where the informal definiton does no longer hold true?

Comment: @TheRelentlessNucleophile It would be considered a function if you've defined it at that point, I was talking about the graph since you have two empty circles you haven't given it value. I probably worded it confusing. The informal definition generally applies when the domain is R or connected, but you can look at each connected component individually. So here $c$ is the hole looking at $(-\infty, c) $ it's connected and it's connected from $(c, \infty) $ since $c$ is not in the domain there's no way to bridge the gap from the first to the secons component so you can look at them individually.